# Manifest signature did not verify successfully

Tags: ios, .net, passbook

I'm implementing passbook to our app which is working fine on Android but now so well in iOS and Mac OS, probably due to its signature or certifications.

I have 2 files for the certificates:

1. company.pfx (valid until 2021)
2. AppleWWDRCA.cer (latest one)

And also have the password for that .pfx file.

I'm using the **[dotnet-passbook](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook)** framework in a .NET MVC Webapi, also you can find my issue in the repository **[here](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook/issues/69)**.

---

I'm using the following code to generate de **.pkpass** file:

```
     public static byte[] Generate(Models.PassKey.PassBookTicketData data)
      {
        // Generator to get the passkey
        var generator = new PassGenerator();

        string appleCertPath = (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/AppleWWDRCA.cer"));
        string companyCertPath = (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/company.pfx"));

        // Request to send
        var request = new PassGeneratorRequest()
        {
            PassTypeIdentifier = "pass.com.company",
            TeamIdentifier = "TEAM",
            Certificate = File.ReadAllBytes(companyCertPath),
            CertificatePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PASSBOOK_PASSWORD"],
            AppleWWDRCACertificate = File.ReadAllBytes(appleCertPath),
            SerialNumber = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Description = data.Description,
            OrganizationName = "some organization",
            BackgroundColor = ColorHexToPassBookColor("#00517c"),
            ForegroundColor = ColorHexToPassBookColor("#f68700"),
            LabelColor = ColorHexToPassBookColor("#ffffff"),
            LogoText = "some text",
            GroupingIdentifier = data.EventCode
        };

             // .... images, icons, fields, etc

             return generator.Generate(request);
       }
```

It's missing the part where you add the fields, images, icons but that is irrelevant right now, I created a **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/emimontesdeoca/b242d906d715d9e1d8ca315103facda4)** with the entire code if you need it.

---

**Do I need to make a new cert when send it, to make it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of dotnet-passbook and I helped Emiliano resolve this issue on Github.

The problem was the pfx certificate being used to sign the manifest.

This certificate wasn't generated from the Apple Developer portal and, as a result, it was missing required information. I ran the pass through my validation tool (https://pkpassvalidator.azurewebsites.net) and this gave me an idea of what the issue was. Once I'd established that the pass type identifier and team identifier values differed, I investigated the certificate further.

You can read the full history of the issue here - https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook/issues/69

Comment: Glad you answered here, I made this post at the same time as issue in Github and then forgot about it, thanks again!